# Pedal that stays horizontal

Tags: pedals

Sometime when I step on the pedal my foot slips off because the pedal is in vertical position, not a horizontal position.

I used to own pedals that always stayed in a horizontal position, but I forget the brand name.

Do you know a platform pedal that always stays horizontal?

Comment: I would suggest working on your technique a bit: Your feet should generally never leave the pedals while you are seated on your bike. Including when you are leaning at a light post when stopped at the lights. And when you hop off your pedal to stop where there is no post to lean against, one foot remains on its pedal in the right position for accelerating. When you start from such a position, the foot that's not on the pedal should move onto the pedal from above/behind, which will automatically orient the platform pedal horizontally without danger of slipping off the pedal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any current pedal with those properties, but an old example is Shimano's Adamas AX touring pedal, which you can often find for purchase used. These pedals are weighted on the underside at the spindle so that they remain horizontal. Here is a view of the underside where you can see the weighted portion:

[image]

I have seen plastic copies of these pedals, but I do not know what brand they were. I suspect there are other similar variations out there.

Comment: I have only seen Shimano's plastic/resin version of this pedal which is model PD-D100. They are quite comfortable and I've seen a few sets on 1980s Raleigh bikes.

Answer (score 1):

There are clipless pedals that hang at a specific angle, to help with clipping-in.

But I've never heard of a platform pedal that is weighted.  You could duplicate the effect by screwing a block of wood to one side, which would then hang down.

Shopping questions tend to be off-topic, sorry.  Read the [tour] to learn more.

Comment: Shimano Adamas AX touring pedals and other brands’ similar offerings are examples of weighted platform pedals.

Comment: Funny enough, Shimano and Look road pedals are weighted as described, and they are weighted such that they hang near vertical. I am not sure how one might weight a platform pedal so that it stays horizontal, unless we are talking about putting toe clips on a quill pedal - the toe clips will tend to stay down, I think.

Comment: @WeiwenNg cleated pedals are angled to assist with clipping in.  For platforms, one could try a weight centered in the middle of the axle when the platform is level, though there would be an aero cost, and an increased risk of pedal strike.   One could also replace the pedal body with a square cross-section, so there are four pedal faces.   Or simply work on one's technique when placing the foot.